# Conjecture about Proving Primality of Fermat numbers by Elliptic Curves technic

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, conjectures, primality-test, fermat-numbers

In 2008 and 2009, Denomme-Savin and Tsumura provided 2 papers providing a Primality Test for Fermat numbers based on Elliptic Curves technic:

$$ \text{Let } DST(x)= \frac{\displaystyle x^4+2x^2+1}{\displaystyle 4(x^3-x)}
\ \text{ and } \  F_n = 2^{2^n}+1 $$
$$ \text{Let } x_1=F_1=\pm 5, \ x_{j+1} = DST(x_j)$$
$$ \text{If } x_{2^{n-1}} \equiv \mp 1 \pmod{F_n} \ , \ \text{then } F_n  \text{ is prime.}$$

Now, can you prove the following conjecture (which makes use of a BigTree of the DiGraph):

$$\text{Let } x_1 = \pm 4 \ , \  x_{j+1} = DST(x_j) $$
$$\text{If } x_{2^{n-1}} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n} \ , \ \text{then } F_n  \text{ is prime}.$$

And, then, can you prove the following conjecture (which makes use of a Cycle of the DiGraph):

$$\text{Let } x_1 = \pm 1/3 \ , \  x_{j+1} = DST(x_j) $$
$$\text{If } x_{2^{n}-1} \equiv x_1 \pmod{F_n} \ , \ \text{then } F_n  \text{ is prime}.$$

R. Denomme and G. Savin, “Elliptic curve primality tests for fermat and related primes,” Journal of Number Theory, vol. 128, no. 1, pp. 2398–2412, 2008.

Y. Tsumura, “Elliptic curve primality tests for fermat and related primes” 2009.

Comment: Since there is almost no hope to find another Fermat prime , this test is of very little practical use.

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes, you are right. And I know this will be of very little practical use. However, it is a first step for extending the EC proof technic. The Denomme-Savin-Tsumura technic makes use of two BigTrees (ending at 1 or -1) of the DiGraph under DST(x) modulo a Fermat number. There is a third BigTree, ending at 0 (like the LLT test for Mersennes).

Comment: And, after, I have another conjecture which makes use of a Cycle of this DiGraph. If someone would succeed to prove my second conjecture, it would be (AFAIK) the first time such a Cycle of a DiGraph is used for building a Primality Proof. Then, such a technic could be used for other numbers, like the Wagstaff number, for which there are several PRP proofs, but NO primality proof.
If you have Elliptic Curves skills, please have a look. I've started to study EC, but it will take me years before I master it, or - more probably - I'll never master it enough.

Comment: I don't understand this post, as it says there are some results in some papers and asserts that some things can be proved, but then doesn't ask anything about those results or their application.  The problem title mentions a conjecture, but nothing in the body is stated to be a conjecture? What is the conjecture? What is the question? Or is this post merely meant to advertise those two papers?

Comment: Hi Aaron, At the beginning, I wanted only to talk about one conjecture, which seemed to me the easiest. However, answering Peter, I added the second one, more difficult since (AFAIK) no primality proof was ever built on using a Cycle. As an example, the famous LLT test for Mersenne makes use of the BigTree of the DiGraph under x^2-2 modulo a Mersenne, starting from 4 and reaching 0. About DiGraph, maybe you should have a look at this paper (figure 6) : https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tmjvasig/papers/newvasiga.pdf